# Explaining of (3/2 x^(1/2))^2

Tags: calculus

I haven't taken math in a while and in my textbook there's this part to a problem that I don't quite understand. It's where L = the integral 1 to 2 of the sqrt(1 + (3/2 x^(1/2))^2)dx and they use u substitution to get u = 1 + 9/4x, du = 9/4x. I'm stuck at how they got (3/2 x^(1/2))^2 to = 9/4x.

Comment: They're basically using the fact that $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$ for real numbers.

Comment: I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\large\left(\frac32 x^{\frac12}\right)^2=\left(\frac32\right)^2\left(x^{\frac12}\right)^2=\frac94x^{\frac12\times2}=\frac94x$$

Comment: This makes it more clear, thanks!